determining orientation of simplex from boundary matrices
Let $[v_0, \ldots, v_n]$ be an oriented simplex.
If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are $k$- and $k - 1$-dimensional faces, and if $\tau$ can be obtained from $\sigma$ by removing vertex $j$ from $\sigma$, then the incidence coefficient between $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is $(-1)^j$.
Applying this relation systematically, we can get a chain complex, i.e. set of integer matrices $E_0, \ldots, E_n$ such that $E_k\cdot E_{k + 1} = 0$, where by convention $E_0 = \mathbf{1}^*$ is the row vector of all 1s.
Given any chain complex, let $P$ be a permutation matrix and $s$ a vector all of whose entries are $\pm 1$.
Then if we take
$$E_k' = E_k\cdot P\cdot\text{diag}(s), \qquad E_{k + 1}' = \text{diag}(s)\cdot P^* \cdot E_{k + 1},$$
then the chain complex $\{E_0, \ldots, E_k', E_{k + 1}', \ldots, E_n\}$ is essentially the same as the original one.
All we've done is reorder some cells and flip signs of intermediate faces.
Now suppose that we have a chain complex $\{D_0, \ldots, D_n\}$ that we know was obtained by some permutations and sign flips from either the simplex $+[v_0, \ldots, v_n]$  or $-[v_0, \ldots, v_n]$.
The goal is to determine which orientation the original chain complex has.
The only way I know to do this involves explicitly constructing the chain complex of a standard simplex (with one ordering of the vertices or the other) and finding an isomorphism of chain complexes.
So we first form the canonical boundary matrices $E_0, \ldots, E_n$ of the positively-oriented simplex using the ordering $v_0, \ldots, v_n$.
Next, for each dimension $1 \le k < n$, we find a permutation matrix $P_k$ and a vector $s_k$ of sign flips such that
$$\text{diag}(s_{k - 1})P_{k - 1}^*D_kP_k\text{diag}(s_k) = E_k$$
where as the base case we take $s_0$ to be all 1s and $P_0$ to be the identity.
Finally, if this chain complex really was obtainable from the standard simplex, then the matrix $\text{diag}(s_{n - 1})P_{n - 1}^*D_n$ will be equal to either $+E_n$ or $-E_n$.
The result is whatever that sign happens to be.
Is there an alternative that does not involve explicitly finding the isomorphism?
This is all going into a software library.
The explicit isomorphism approach works just fine and isn't too hard to code, but I'd sure like it if it were faster.
